# GearmanClient::do(): send_packet(GEARMAN_COULD_NOT_CONNECT) Failed in php shell_exec

Tags: php, centos, shell-exec, gearman

I am trying to run gearman client from php shell_exec but it always throw following error GearmanClient::do(): send_packet(GEARMAN_COULD_NOT_CONNECT) Failed to send server-options packet -> libgearman/connection.cc:485 in /var/www/html/client.php

But if i run it from terminal then it works but not from php shell_exec. Even i passed server name and port in addServer method

I am running on centos 6.2.

Client.php

```
       $client= new GearmanClient();  
       $client->addServer('127.0.0.1',4730);
       print $client->do("reverse","Testing");
```

worker.php

```
      $worker= new GearmanWorker();
      $worker->addServer("127.0.0.1",4730);
      $worker->addFunction("reverse", "my_reverse_function");
      function my_reverse_function($job)
      {
        return strrev($job->workload());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your gearman packages are installed. Or manually installed if needed. Sometimes upgrading your system may cause your packages to be lost.

Second check your or launch it in debug mode as stated here http://gearman.org/getting-started/

```
gearmand -vvv
```

and then launch it run in the background

```
gearmand -d
```

I read on other questions treated to this matter that changes from

```
$woker->addServer('127.0.0.1',4730);
```

to

```
$worker->addServer('127.0.0.1:4730');
```

The same for `$client->addServer('127.0.0.1',4730);`